# Number of invertible elements in a ring $\mathbb{Z}_n$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I know that:

> *a number* $a\in\mathbb{Z}_n$ *is invertible iff* $\text{gcd}(a,n)=1$.

So say $n=2019$. How can I find the number of invertible elements in $\mathbb{Z_{2019}}$? Surely testing $2019$ numbers for primality is out of the question.

Also, if $a=32$, what is its inverse? In my book they state that

> *An inverse in modular arithmetic is a number* $a\in\mathbb{Z}_n$ *if there exists a number in* $\mathbb{Z}_n$ *such that if multiplied by*
>   $a$ *give*s $1$.

So from this I understand that I need to find an $x\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that

$$32\cdot x\equiv 1(\text{mod}\ 2019).$$ This is the same as solving the diophantine equation

$$32x=1+2019y\Leftrightarrow32x-2019y=1,$$

which has trivial solution $(x,y)=(-694,-11)$. So the inverse of $32$ is $-694?$

Comment: The number of invertible elements is given by the Euler totient function, which has an explicit  formula in terms of the prime factorization. Look it up.

Comment: Have you factored $2019$ yet? That would be a sensible first step in checking which numbers are coprime to it.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг - We have not covered Eulers totient function and it's not part of this course.

Comment: @Servaes - Yes, just divided it by three since $2+0+1+9$ is divisible by $3$, so is $2019$. I got that $2019=3\cdot 673$. However, on an exam, I need to motivate how I know that $673$ is a prime, no calculators allowed. How Do I now find the coprimes?

Comment: Well it suffices to check that it is not divisible by the primes less than $\sqrt{673}<26$, which is a bit of work but not hard. Then a number is coprime to $2019$ if it is not divisible by $3$ and not divisible by $673$. I leave it to you to count how many such numbers there are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second question, your reasoning is correct. Indeed the inverse of $32$ in $\Bbb{Z}/2019\Bbb{Z}$ is $-694$, though perhaps a representative in the interval $[0,2018]$ is preferred.

For the first question, it helps to first know the prime factors of $2019$. It is not hard to check that $2019=3\times673$ and that $3$ and $673$ are prime. Then an integer in the interval $[0,2018]$ is coprime to $2019$ if and only if it is not divisible by $3$ and not divisible by $673$. I leave it to you (for now) to count how many such integers there are.

Comment: Great! So to go from $-694$ to somewhere positive, I simply add $2019$ right? I'll give the first part a go and see what I can do. I'll return If I get stuck.

Comment: That's right, and good luck.

Comment: I don't understand why this is true: "Then an integer in the interval $[0,2018]$ is coprime to $2019$ if and only if it is not divisible by $3$ and not divisible by $673$." Could you please elaborate?

Comment: If an integer is *not* coprime to $2019$, then it shares a common prime factor with $2019$, which must be either $3$ or $673$ (or both).

Comment: I have no idea how to find these numbers. Any number upp to and excluding 673 is clearly not divisible by 673, but 673 is a prime so its not divisible by 3. So the next multiple of 673 is 1346, which is not divisible by 3 either. The next multiple takes us outside of $[0,2018]$, so there are no such numbers.

Comment: Precisely. You can do the same for the number $3$; every third number is divisible by $3$, the rest is not.

Comment: But should these number not be divisible by 3 AND 673, (simultaneously) or not be divisible by 3 OR 673? There is a difference here. So there are 672 multiples of 3 in 2018, but none of these are divisible by 673, so the answer is there are no inverses?

Comment: The numbers should not be divisible by $3$, and not be divisible by $673$. Note that if a number is divisible by both, then it is divisible by $3\times673=2019$; the only such number in the interval is $0$.

Comment: Thanks man, I eventually realised this after thinking harder than usual!